# Smart Encapsulation from similar objects

Tags: c#, soap, reflection, derived-class

I have a few Soap-requests that all start the same:
First request:

```
var client = new Conn.Team.z_proj_team_spQueryPortClient();
client.Endpoint.Address = EndPoint;
var query = new Conn.Team.z_proj_team_spQuery
{
    Filter = new Conn.Team.z_proj_team_spFilter
    {
        param_code = projectCode
    }
};
var auth = new Conn.Team.Auth { Username = _username, Password = _password };
var records = client.Query(auth, query).Records;
```

second request:

```
var client = new Conn.Task.z_proj_Task_spQueryPortClient();
client.Endpoint.Address = EndPoint;
var query = new Conn.Task.z_proj_Task_spQuery
{
    Filter = new Conn.Task.z_proj_Task_spFilter
    {
        param_code = projectCode
    }
};
var auth = new Conn.Task.Auth { Username = _username, Password = _password };
var records = client.Query(auth, query).Records;
```

As you can see, the code *looks* nearly the same, but these are completely different objects (that do not share a base class) but who use the same property-names.

Because I have about 10 of these calls, is there a good way to wrap these functions? Would you even advice to do so or would Reflection simple makes it "more evil"?

(BTW:) I am unsure what a good tag would be for my problem. Feel free to change them to better ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this the following "reflection/dynamic" way. Feel free to post a better solution if you have one.

```
private object Connect(Type clientType, Type queryType, Type filterType, Type authType, string code)
{
    dynamic client = Activator.CreateInstance(clientType);
    client.Endpoint.Address = EndPoint;

    dynamic query = Activator.CreateInstance(queryType);
    dynamic filter = Activator.CreateInstance(filterType);
    filter.param_code = code;
    query.Filter = filter;

    dynamic auth = Activator.CreateInstance(authType);
    auth.Username = _username;
    auth.Password = _password;

    return client.Query(auth, query).Records;
}
```